# Javascript client library to resize images and change their canvas size

Tags: gratis, library, javascript, image-processing

I am developing a Javascript application (runs in the browser, not a Node app or similar) and I have a requirement: in my app I have images (jpegs and pngs) in Blob form and I want to manipulate them in the following way:

- I need to resize the images to a certain max resolution
- I need to bring the images to a specific aspect ratio (without distorting them, meaning: if the image is not already at the correct aspect ratio I want to add a filler color to the left/right or top/bottom in order to bring it to the desired aspect ratio)

The library needs to be free to use (gratis).

I have found libraries that can accomplish the first step (e.g.: Pica) but I'm having trouble finding something that fulfills my second requirement.

Answer (score -1):

If you set width in percentage, the pictures get nicely resized. For more advanced setting, use code such as

```
.hide {display:none!important}
@media (min-width:1px) and (max-width: 587px) {.hide-small{display:none!important}}
@media (min-width:588px) and (max-width:900px) {.hide-medium{display:none!important}}
@media (min-width:901px) and (max-width:10000px) {.hide-large{display:none!important}}
```

The idea is that you code so that the javascript executed depends upon the screen size of the viewer.

For more info, search for "Responsive Web Design".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think you completely misunderstood the question my friend... I'm not trying to display images, I'm trying to modify images... raw image data I mean, i.e.: png/jpeg data that I have in memory in a byte array (Blob). CSS/HTML are of no use here.